# Deserializing XML into models without all the fuzz

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I have a plain old XML-file. Through some `XSD.EXE` magic I made a model. Now I want to read the XML data into the model. Normally this is just `XmlSerializer.Deserialize`, but it keeps complaining about namespaces and whatnot.

Now here is the thing: I don't care about namespaces, or anything else in XML. I just want the deserialization to work with a "simple one-liner". I'm planning to parse a lot of XML in my life and I'm not interested in spending my time fighting a bloated format about details we both know aren't important.

So I'm looking for a XML Deserializer for .Net that removes the fuzz and simply sees a `<obj> <Name> ...` and puts its data into `public string Name { get; set; }`. It should not be more difficult than for example `MyObj myObj = SimpleXml.Deserialize<MyObj>(xmlString);`. Pretty much like JSON deserializers work.

Where can I find an easy to use XML deserializer like the one I described?

I do understand that this limits my XML reading capability.

Comment: You are not asking a question. As to the question I _think_ you are asking: You could easily write an extension method that does all the itty gritty namespace referencing for you, then just use that in the future.

Comment: I am looking for something. If it needs to be in question form then just imagine that it ends with "Does anyone know of this?" or "Can anyone help me?" or whatever other vague diffuse and probably wrongly stated question one would normally add. :)

Comment: I don't understand how an extension method would help me when XmlSerializer.Deserialize fails. I could of course write my own XML parser, but I thought I'd leave that for another day.
The whole point of my question .. err.. statement is to find a cheap easy lazy way of reading XML data into models.

Comment: @TeddHansen Why don't you show an example XML that is failing, your XSD.exe generated class, and the code that you have tried to deserialize the XML.  It will make helping a lot easier.  As it is now, we can only guess at what is wrong and can't even try it ourselves.

Comment: @TeddHansen also, your edit to add `Where can I an easy to use XML deserializer like the one I described?` turns your troubleshooting question into a shopping list question.  If that is what you really want to ask, you are going to risk this question getting closed as `Not Constructive`

Comment: Try posting an example XML, the model generated and the code you use to deserialize. Then it should be easier to come up with an answer for you, but in general: Namespaces in XML _can be_ a pain in the butt, but you should be able to generalize the pain away with some code that you only write once.

Comment: @psubsee2003: The whole point is that I don't want to tackle these problems. XML is imho bloated and used everywhere and I just want an easy way to read it. This one specific problem I can of course just solve now. But then next time its the same problem in new wrapping, or a while new problem. Its not my first encounter with problems related to reading XML, so trying to make it my last.

If my question is faulty (I added a missing word now) then please educate me. "Everyone" knows what I mean, but SO seems to be more pedantic than helpful at times.

Comment: Well I realize my answer is only applicable if you serialize/deserialize your own objects. I think what you are looking for is Transparent DeSerialization.

Comment: Yes, if I had control over it myself then it wouldn't be any problem. And I would probably use ServiceStack to make it all a 2-liner. Sadly ServiceStack uses DataContractSerializer and therefore doesn't work on everything.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this kind of helpers for my UI clients.

```
public string Serialize<T>(T o)
{
    var x = new XDocument();
    using(var w = x.CreateWriter())
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Serialize(w, o);
    return x.ToString();
}

public T Deserialize<T>(string s)
{
    return
        (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))
        .Deserialize(XDocument.Parse(s)
        .CreateReader());
}
```

Beware if you are using windows services, there is a known memory leak in Serialization: http://dotnetcodebox.blogspot.fr/2013/01/xmlserializer-class-may-result-in.html

To avoid this, I suggest you to replace the `new XmlSerializer` of the code above by a method that creates/retrieves XmlSerializers from a cache (a Dictionary for example) as it is explained in the blog post.

Comment: +1 for the memory leak. Already knew about it, but that's a very important thing to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issues by using xsd.exe, I don't want to have a huge autogenereted file that I need to fix to make it work, and I spent hours on making the deserialization kind of work with hacks and removing of namespaces, blah.

If you want a one-line solution with no fuzz, try [xsd2code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/) (http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/), it just works. 
Be aware that you need to read the little guide on the generating of the classes so you get all the settings right before generating, you can't just click generate, at least for me it didn't have the correct default settings but it was a breeze to set correctly.

So I did:

1. Generated the xsd with xsd.exe (xsd Hoorah.xml), that part of xsd.exe is okay.
2. Generated the classes with xsd2code (install and see the guide)
3. Used the deserialize method that comes with the generated class from xsd2code

   ```
   var hoorah = Hoorah.Deserialize(xml);
   ```

Just works!